# Why some permissions of Android are not listed in the original Android Developers page?

Tags: android, permissions, android-manifest, apk, deprecated

What is the difference between the **ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION** and **ACCESS_COARSE** Android permission?

The **ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION** can be found in the [Android developers page](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html),
whether the **ACCESS_COARSE** is not in this list.

I have found many applications that use it e.g. [3D Compass](http://m.slideme.org/application/3d-compass).
I run the [androguard](http://code.google.com/p/androguard/) to inspect the permissions of this application and I found this one inside:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE">
```

Is it an abbreviation of the **ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION**? Why is it not in the official Android page with the permissions [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html)?

Moreover I have see several other permissions not in this list such as:
**WRITE_OWNER_DATA**, **READ_OWNER_DATA**,...

Why does it happen? Are those permission deprecated, or not official?

Comment: some permissions are only for internal use by the android framework and can't be used by apps. I don't know if that's the case for the ones you mentioned.

Comment: ok, so why does the mentioned app request this permissions if it cannot use it?

Comment: You can request any permissions that you want. If that permission does not exists it is ignored. If the permission requires system privileges it is not granted. Maybe that permission existed for older versions of android or maybe it's just an error.

Comment: if you google ["android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE"](https://www.google.com/search?q="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE") you find that a lot of people seem to be doing it wrong. Might be caused by statements like "Some network SDKs may also utilize android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE/FINE_LOCATION" being misunderstood

Comment: Yes I agree with you too! I did a lot of searches in google before posting this question and came into the same thoughts-conclusions!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> What is the difference between the ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION and ACCESS_COARSE Android permission?

There is no `ACCESS_COARSE` permission in Android. You can tell this by looking [at the source code](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/res/AndroidManifest.xml).

> The ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION can be found in the Android developers page, whether the ACCESS_COARSE is not in this list.

Because `ACCESS_COARSE` does not exist.

> I have found many applications that use it e.g. 3D Compass.

They might request it. They do not use it, because it does not exist.

> I run the androguard to inspect the permissions of this application and I found this one inside:

Presumably the authors of that application made a mistake.

> Is it an abbreviation of the ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION?

No.

> Why is it not in the official Android page with the permissions here?

Because it does not exist.

> Moreover I have see several other permissions not in this list such as: WRITE_OWNER_DATA, READ_OWNER_DATA

[Those were removed from the SDK in API Level 9.](http://developer.android.com/sdk/api_diff/9/changes.html)

> Why does it happen?

You can have any `<uses-permission>` elements you want. If what you request does not exist, you do not get it.

> ok, so why does the mentioned app request this permissions if it cannot use it?

Presumably because the million monkeys they used to write the app put it in there. This is one of the many reasons not to use monkeys (outside of specially prepared test monkeys and monkey runners) for Android application development.